# Transitioning to Git from no version control

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm moving my workflow for a bunch of simple HTML only files to Git.

Currently I've been using no version control system for this area, so my file system looks like:

- 1.0_project.html
- 1.1_project.html
- 1.5_project.html
- 2.0_project.html

And so on, for each version and project.

How would you move from a non version control workflow to Git?

I've created a repository for each project. Should I commit the first version of the HTML then overwrite it, and commit again (and tag it with a version number in Git), or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is this the best/only way to do it? I've got quite a few projects I want to convert over, so it could be time-consuming...

Comment: There are two ways to do this. You can either do what @duffymo suggests, or you can convince someone else to do it for you. The way you managed your code previously is not any kind of standard, so there are no standard tools to automate bringing your code into modern, uh, standards.

Comment: It is the only and therefore the best way. There's no git function that can rename the files, commit them one by one and add tags that reflect some part of the filename. But you could script it, if the actual "version number" pattern is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick script that works for the files you listed.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=project.html

# Setup repository
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit README -m "Initial commit"

# Create each commit and tag
for f in ./*_$FILE
do
    echo "Processing $f"
    version="${f:2:3}"
    cp $f $FILE
    git add $FILE
    git commit -m "Version $version"
    git tag -a -m "Version $version" "v$version"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you strictly sticked to the kind of standard you made up (say, `version-project.html` or similar for every project you have), you probably can mess with the [Custom Importer](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#A-Custom-Importer) provided in the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/) for doing that.

The example uses dates, but changing that to using versions would be not-so-bad, I hope. GNU `sort` has a [`--version-sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort) parameter, if that helps.